# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error issue

Tags: sql, query, delete

[image]

Whem i am trying to fetch sql query in my magento's controller
it's display this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
```

HERE is my code

```
    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    $sql = "DELETE FROM marketplace_sellernotification WHERE seller_id =".$sellerId;
    $rows = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: try this code:-my.cnf settings that might help…
max_allowed_packet = 16M
wait_timeout = 1800 
connect_timeout = 120

Comment: please tell  me code of line 1362 at SellerController.php

Comment: $rows = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

Comment: I hope you are sanitizing `$sellerId` to always be an integer. Better: use prepared statements. Even better: use the appropiate Magento resource model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi first you need change  **core_read** to **core_write**
from

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
```

to

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
```

Now run query by checking carefully ,sure it will work